# SQL Server SSMS Default SELECT TOP <n> ROWS from SQL can I change the Order as a Default setting?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I get that we can right-click and `SELECT TOP <n> ROWS` from any given table in SSMS, is there any way to change this default script to that it also orders the records with `ORDER BY 1 DESC`?

What I would really like to increase my productiveness is

```
Right-click - SELECT TOP <n> ROWS ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Or do I have to have a snippet so once the records are returned that I then have to paste a the snippet in?

Or even bind a stored procedure to a keyboard shortcut?

Many thanks

Comment: SQL Server 2023? The latest version is 2022 and, as far as I've heard, there's no plans for a release this year

Comment: I don't believe the template is exposed in a way that you could add an `ORDER BY` (never mind that `ORDER BY <ordinal>` is a [bad practice](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal) to promote). Maybe some SSMS add-ins provide additional options here, or you could write one.

Comment: Select SSMS Options > Object Explorer Options > Commands

Comment: @Bogdan That dialog only allows you to set how many rows to return, not the order. [Where can we change the order here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQUc8.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to customize what text appears in the query window when you use the menu options in the GUI. This code is buried somewhere in the bowels of the executable and/or DLLs.

I would suggest using a snippet instead of the point-and-click stuff. Or if you really want to customize the UI, see if any existing SSMS add-in does this, or write your own. It might be easier these days to build such a thing for Azure Data Studio, though.

Comment: Many thanks, there are a tonne of things that annoy me with SSMS and this is one of those that would save me so much time.     I'm currently trolling through GITHUB looking for a decent example of how to create an extension, I can then try to code my own so fingers crossed.